# Why do I get a TempVars Only Store Data not Objects when TempVars Store objects

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I was recently volunteered to finish off a Access database that a colleague had completed about 99% of before she left to another job. the db is being used as a Library Check In/Check Out database.

There is an action button that 'On Click' runs an Event procedure that is written in VBA. Upon clicking the action button I get the error "TempVars can only store data, they cannot store objects".

I don't have any prior experience with VBA or Access so I don't what's broken or how to fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Private Sub Action_Click()
On Error GoTo Action_Click_Err

' _AXL:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
' <UserInterfaceMacro For="Owner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application"><Statements><ConditionalBlock><If><Condition>IsNull([Screen].[ActiveControl])</C
' _AXL:ondition><Statements><Action Name="StopMacro"/></Statements></If></ConditionalBlock><Action Name="OpenForm"><Argument Name="FormName">Contact Details</Argument><Argument Name="WhereCondition">="[ID]=" &amp; [Screen].[ActiveControl]</Argument><Argum
' _AXL:ent Name="WindowMode">Dialog</Argument></Action><Action Name="OnError"/><Action Name="Requery"><Argument Name="ControlName">=[Screen].[ActiveControl].[Name]</Argument></Action></Statements></UserInterfaceMacro>
If (IsNull(ID)) Then
    Beep
    Exit Sub
End If
TempVars.Add "ItemID", ID
If (Nz([Contact Name]) <> "") Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Check In", acNormal, "", "[Transactions].[Asset]=[TempVars]![ItemID] And [Transactions].[Checked In Date] Is Null", acEdit, acDialog
End If
If (Nz([Contact Name]) = "") Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Check Out", acNormal, "", "1=0", acEdit, acDialog
End If
DoCmd.Requery ""


Action_Click_Exit:
    Exit

 Sub

Action_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Action_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have `Sub` within procedure? I've never used TempVars. Unless the value in TempVars variable needs to be used by multiple procedures, really no need for it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solution in a cross post.https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=81031. `TempVars.Add "ItemID", ID.Value`

Answer (score 1):

Lacking more detail, I'm making some assumptions. If 'ID' is a control (bound to a number field) on your form, likely Access is trying to set the TempVar to the control, rather than it's value. As mentioned, I don't see a need for a TempVar anyway. Replace the block with the below code:

```
Dim lngID as Long 
lngID = Nz(Me!ID, 0)
If lngID = 0 Then
    Beep
    Exit Sub
End If
If (Nz([Contact Name]) <> "") Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Check In", acNormal, "", "[Transactions].[Asset]=" & lngID & " And [Transactions].[Checked In Date] Is Null", acEdit, acDialog
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft documentation:

> A TempVar object can store only text or numeric data. TempVar objects cannot store objects.

Source: [TempVar object (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.tempvar)

You need to come up with a different solution if you *really* need to store the object in memory.